# Vertically Centered Loading Spinner Overlay

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, polymer

I would like to show a vertically centered loading spinner like one of these https://github.com/jlong/css-spinners in a web page. Follow the codepen.io link on that page to see them in motion.

How can I do this via CSS? Consider I am dealing with a Google App Engine application based on Python, Twitter Bootstrap and Polymer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Let's assume you go with the "Plus" spinner. You can wrap this in a fixed position div that covers the whole page:

```
<div id="pluswrap">
  <div class="plus">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Since you might want to use different spinners at times, which have a different width, the CSS shouldn't hardcode the width. You can center an item vertically in a flexbox, and then use `margin: 0 auto;` on the item to be centered horizontally.

```
#pluswrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
}

.plus {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This way, you can even color the background, make it semi-transparent etc.

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nxaj2pu/)

Comment: Thank you, it works. It is also vertically centered but not horizontally :( I can't see why

Comment: If you wrap it in a fixed-position flexbox I don't see why it shouldn't be horizontally centered. Can you share the code or page to help pinpoint the problem?

Comment: justify-content: center; !

Comment: you can do in polymer way by using horizontal center-justified layout attributes

Comment: @GeorgeKormaris... You have used some not required properties,... see my answer below for changes in your answer

Comment: You saved the day. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything  about a google app engine I'm afraid but to centre an element that has a width and height is pretty easy.

I assume this is a fixed positioned element so just use top,right,left and bottom and then use margin:auto to center vertically and horizontally.

e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.spinner{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:99;/* make higher than whatever is on the page */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="spinner"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## HTML

```
<div id="pluswrap">
  <div class="plus">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#pluswrap {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
}

.plus {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Only `display:flex` to parent and `margin: auto` will do the required thing.

Here is [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nxaj2pu/350/)