# how to show spinner at the top of component in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a web app where I have included a spinner from this link

https://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/

I am able to show the spinner from my Interceptor component but it is showing in the Bottom of the screen

[image]

Here is my app component

```
<app-header *ngIf='showHeader'></app-header>
<BR>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-spinner></app-spinner>
```

`Spinner CSS Component`

```
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner > div {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  
  20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%, 40%, 100% { 
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }  20% { 
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

`Spinnr HTML component`

```
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect2"></div>
  <div class="rect3"></div>
  <div class="rect4"></div>
  <div class="rect5"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make spinner to come at the middle of the screen
I am using angular and Bootstrap
Any help would be appreciated

Note -  I tried this link and its not working for me
[Vertically Centered Loading Spinner Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26451948/vertically-centered-loading-spinner-overlay)

Comment: No, It i showing at the bottom of the screen and want it in middle of the screen
Corrected my question

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use as a reference the example provided for the HTTP requests from the tables in angular material [example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http).

They use the following CSS on the mat spinner element:

`CSS`

```css
.example-loading-shade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 56px;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.example-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

`HTML`

```html
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <div class="example-loading-shade"
       *ngIf="isLoadingResults || isRateLimitReached">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
    <div class="example-rate-limit-reached" *ngIf="isRateLimitReached">
      GitHub's API rate limit has been reached. It will be reset in one minute.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```